# Is it possible and how can redirect to another web page with dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow chatbot in a web page using the web demo integration. Is it possible to redirect to a specific web page using the chatbot?

Something similar like:

User: "Which is the google's web page?
Chatbot: "I will send you to google's web page." (And then Google's web page is shown in the same tab)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow itself won't allow you to redirect a user since Dialogflow doesn't control the client through which the user is chatting to the bot. For example, if the user is speaking to your bot through Facebook messenger or Slack, there would be no way to redirect the user. You have a few options:

1. Your agent simply returns a URL that you format to be clickable.
2. You create a user interface that connects to Dialogflow and use Dialogflow's actions to handle the logic inside your app.